# Watching route change with Laravel Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Using the new Inertia Laravel stack – how do you watch route change?

I am trying to do something very simple in the likes of:

```
watch: {
  route () {
    console.log('You changed route')
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any information on this.

Comment: Where have you passed your route information to Vue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to listen to the `start` event.

```
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'

Inertia.on('start', (event) => {
  console.log(`The route changed to ${event.detail.visit.url}`)
})
```

Note the `start` event is triggered before the load completes. If you want to get notified once the new page is displayed, use the `success` event.

For more info, check out https://inertiajs.com/events

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
watch: {
  '$page.url': function (newUrl, oldUrl) {
    console.log(newUrl)
  }
}
```

Comment: This would only work in a persistent layout.